# Show Internet Connection Dialog on Android Studio with Redirection

Tags: android

*Not a duplicate resource, I have accessed all answers available.

I am trying to build an android studio app.

How can I make it mandatory for the app to show a dialog on the app when there is no connection and then redirect user to activity when there is either mobile or wifi connection.

Users must not be able to quit the dialog until they turn on their Internet connection.

Dialog should automatically disappear when data is on.

I have tried all the codes I see on Stackoverflow, but all codes I have used, none worked some make the app to crash.

What is the simplest way to achieve this result in API 30?

Comment: if you started now follow thi, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HfUgdxhyyPk

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**
Add this Typealias below import file or above class

```
typealias OnRetryInternetConnection = () -> Unit
```

**Step 2:**
Add this code (Custom Alert Dialog)

```
fun internetValidationDialog(
                activity: Activity,
                onRetryInternetConnection: OnRetryInternetConnection
        ) {

            try{
                val mDialogView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.your_custom_layout_with_retry_button, null)
                val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                        .setView(mDialogView)
                val mAlertDialog = mBuilder.show()
                mAlertDialog.setCancelable(false)
                mDialogView.llRetry.setOnClickListener {
                    run {
                        onRetryInternetConnection.invoke()
                    }
                    mAlertDialog.dismiss()
                }
            }catch (e: Exception){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

        }
```

**Step 3:**
This Function will use to check internet connection

```
fun isNetworkConnected(): Boolean {
            var result = false
            val cm = application!!.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager?
            cm?.run {
                cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.activeNetwork)?.run {
                    result = when {
                        hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
                        hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
                        hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
                        else -> false
                    }
                }
            }
            return result
        }
```

**Step 4:**
Add this code where you want to validate the Internet connectivity

> If the internet is not connected it will show the alert dialog and if
> you click the retry button again this method called and come to else
> repeat until condition satisfied.

```
fun callYourNextLogin() {
            button.setOnClickListener {
                when {
                    isNetworkConnected() -> {
                        // Go ahead internet is connected
                    }
                    else -> {
                        internetValidationDialog(requireActivity()) {
                            callYourNextLogin()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Step 5:**
To auto dismiss the internet connection just use Live data to observe.

Comment: Hello, thank you for this answer, step two should u put this code Inside or outside oncreate

Comment: You have add outside the onCreate

Comment: This answer looks detailed and great, but I am getting red allover the codes, I think it's due to the this line you asked to put above class or below import 
"Step 1: Add this Typealias below import file or above class
typealias OnRetryInternetConnection = () -> Unit" The error says, 'class' or 'interface' expected

Comment: Also is this solution in kotlin, my code is in java

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) and register it in your main activity.
The receiver will be notified whenever there is a change in the connection of the device to the internet.

**1.** Create a custom dialog `dialog.xml` in layout. For example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/light_purple"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="You're not connected!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**2.** Create a static method to check the connection status:

```java
public static boolean checkConnection(Context context)
{
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnected();
        return isConnected;
}
```

**3.** Create a new class that extends from `BroadcastReceiver`:

```java
public class OfflineBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    public OfflineBroadcastReceiver() {}

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent)
    {
        // No connection
        if(!checkConnection(context))
        {
            // Activity with dialog
            Intent offline = new Intent(context, Activity.class);
            context.startActivity(offline);
        }
        // Connected
        else
        {
            Intent offline = new Intent(context, OfflineActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(offline);
        }
    }
}
```

**4.** Create the receiver in your launched activity (MainActivity by default) in `onCreate`, add a `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` action to the filter, and register it:

```java
    OfflineBroadcastReceiver offlineForeground = new OfflineBroadcastReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(offlineForeground, filter);
```

5. Add the following permission to your manifest file:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**NOTE:** The receiver will not be notified in the background while the app is not running. You could create a [Manifest declared receiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#manifest-declared-receivers) to do that.

In Github: https://github.com/shahar0809/OfflineReceiver

Comment: Hello thanks for this solution, where should I put the static method you provided in step two, should a create a separate class, or on broadcast receiver class or in main activity?

Comment: You could put it in the broadcast receiver, or in a separate class, there isn't much difference. In my project, I created a static Utils class and put it there :)

Comment: Thanks, the last step  you asked me to put on main activity, should this be inside oncreate method, above setContentView, below SetContentView or outside oncreate method in other to make it work?

Comment: It should be executed when the app is launched, so put it in your launcher activity (MainActivity by default) and in onCreate. Usually all code in onCreate needs to be after setContentVIew because it initializes the view (so the last step should be after too)

Comment: I have been trying to implement this, I think this is the last issue, could you double check the OfflineBrodcastReceiver code is correct, seems to be throwing error some of which says "Method expected" Don't know if the braces are not properly closed or some colon expected, the code for broadcast receiver has errors

Comment: I have researched, and apparently you can't create a dialog from a broadcast receiver. I recommend redirecting to an activity with a dialog if there's no connection.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will check that. I thought that is what the code you have answered is supposed to do?

Comment: The code before opened a dialog from the broadcast receiver, and now it opens a new activity from which a dialog will be created. Both still show a dialog :)